# angular 6 ionic 4 default components not registered

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm working on upgrading my Ionic App to Ionic 4 (pre-release) and Angular 6.  I have a component which uses some of the ionic's components but they seem to not be registered.  I've created a new project and I'm using the Tabs Start,  My Html looks like so:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar align-title="center">
     <ion-title>Home</ion-title
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
```

I changed the home page to use the ion-navbar but now I'm getting an error:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
>   'ion-navbar' is not a known element

Has the nav-bar been removed from Ionic?

Comment: @R.Richards Yeah but the docs are not updated for V4 because its in still in alpha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m sure they’ll update the docs when v4 is release but Incase anyone is wondering the navbar has been removed, they suggest just using the toolbar for now.

```
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
    <ion-back-button></ion-back-button>
  </ion-buttons>
  <ion-title>My Navigation Bar</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

More info for v4 is [Here](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/angular/BREAKING.md#navbar)